# Confusion with Use of "Though"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

Today I came across this sentence:

> Though I don't sell photos taken by me it still makes me feel good/appreciated/wanted

I want to know exactly what this sentence means. I assumed two possible meanings:

1. He doesn't sell photos taken by himself but sells those taken by others. And that makes him feel good.
2. The fact that he doesn't sell photos taken by himself makes him feel good

Which one is the correct interpretation?

Comment: 'It' refers to the selling of photos taken by the speaker. 'Though' indicates there's a *disjunct* in the statement, which rules out your second interpretation. To embody the second meaning you'd have to delete 'though' and replace 'it still' with ', which'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third possible interpretation: the speaker takes photos but does not sell them, and the act of taking photos makes him or her feel good.

Comment: I think thats what i tried to mean in the second case. Couldn't phrase it well. :)

Comment: @Bibhas: It should be noted that the sentence alone does not mean that. The sentence in and of itself tells you one thing and one thing only: that the author doesn't sell photos taken by himself. Anything else will have to be inferred from further context. That is because, as JSBangs points out, the "antecedent of *it* is unclear in this fragment". You cannot possibly tell *what* makes the author feel good. The information is simply not there. It could be picking daffodils, or eating children alive. At any rate, the question as stated does not even match this answer, so it has to be closed.

Answer (score 6):

The correct interpretation is option #1. The word *though* indicates a contrast between the two halves of the sentence, so the sentence means:

- I don't sell photos taken by me
- Nonetheless, it makes me feel appreciated [antecedent of *it* is unclear in this fragment]

In order to suggest meaning #2, the writer would have had to use *because* in place of *though*.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is awkwardly constructed, making it hard to tell, but #1 is close to what it seems to be saying, though I wouldn't say that that it necessarily implies that the speaker sells photos at all.

There is at least a comma missing, and the antecedent of "it" is unclear:

> Though I don't sell photos taken by me, it (taking photos? selling photos?) still makes me feel good/appreciated/wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think it simply means, although/even though he doesn't sell photos taken by himself, it still makes him feel appreciated.

Though is a synonym of although, even though, and despite the fact that.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: *What* makes him feel good? Selling other photos, not selling his own photos, taking photos?

Comment: I think selling photos makes him feel good.